# One-to-Many Relationship with ApplicationUser class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I have this `User` class :

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    }
```

And this `Project` Class :

```
  public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Project` as you can see.
Instead of my `User` class, I want to use `Identity`'s `ApplicationUser` class. So would it be ok if I change `IdentityModels.cs` to this :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

            public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

And How should I change AccountViewModel.cs? should I add these

```
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
```

to every ViewModel in that file?

Finally how should I change `Project` class? Should I do this :

```
 public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
```

If you can answer to my this long question, I would be very glad. Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to use `public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }` inside `IdentityModels.cs`? Shouldn't this be related to `Project.cs`

Comment: I mistakenly pasted those to the question. I edited question. Thanks.